# Получает ли автор вопроса уведомление при изменении ответа?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, уведомления

Встречал неоднократно комментарии отвечающих вида «дополнил ответ, посмотрите» (да и сам так делаю).

Обычно их пишут автору вопроса во время дискуссии, когда выясняются какие-то уточняющие детали.

Получает ли автор вопроса автоматическое уведомление об изменении ответа?

И более конкретно: имеет ли смысл отвечающему писать такой «оповещающий» комментарий?

Comment: Иногда авторы и сам ответ не замечают... Вопрос только в ком проблема - в авторах или в оповещениях.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно [публикации о запуске общего ящика уведомлений](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/) в блоге компании, вы получите уведомление, если:

- будет опубликован ответ на ваш вопрос;
- будет опубликован комментарий к вашему сообщению;
- вам ответят используя ваш @псевдоним на сайте в комментариях.

---

P. S. С момента запуска прошло достаточно много времени. Постараюсь уточнить текущую логику работы уведомлений в ближайшее время.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю не дожидаться квалифицированного ответа, а провести эксперимент.

Я отредактирую этот вопрос через 10 минут.

---

Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: возможно, на мете устроено несколько иначе. впрочем, жду.

Comment: нет, оповещения не получил.

Comment: Зато можно нажать на `изменен %time% часов/минут назад` и посмотреть правки

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Подождите пару минут, возможно, нотификации приходят не сразу.

Comment: возможно. хотя нотификации о комментариях приходят «мгновенно».

Comment: Прошло 17 минут, нотификации не было?

Comment: ничего не пришло по поводу изменения вопроса. ну, значит, комментариям вида «дополнил/изменил ответ» — быть.

Comment: Нотификация? Не, не слышал.

Comment: Я бы сказал, это неправильно, нотификации должны приходить (хотя бы кумулятивные). Надо запросить у Николаса в чате.

Comment: Кстати, а вот в [_чат_](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) пришла обновлённая версия ответа.

Comment: ну и так, к слову об оповещениях, я не получил оповещения ни об одном из четырёх последних комментариев (начиная с «Прошло 17 минут»). а, вроде бы, автор вопроса, по идее, должен бы получать оповещения обо **всех** комментариях, не только к вопросу, но и к ответам на свой вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Насколько я помню, оповещение о комментариях к вопросу/ответу приходят автоматически лишь к автору вопроса/ответа. Например, мне приходят нотификации о комментариях к этому ответу. Если кто-то хочет, чтобы и вас оповестили о комментарии, он должен упомянуть вас через @.

Comment: @VladD, я, конечно, в курсе о том, что написано в справке. просто мне кажется несколько нелогичным *не оповещать* автора вопроса о комментариях к ответам. пусть и хотя бы кумулятивно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Не знал, что это есть в справке :) Насколько я понимаю, это сделано в расчёте на трафик большого SO, на котором бывают длинные обсуждения в многочисленных ответах, и автор _вопроса_ получал бы тогда буквально сотни нотификаций. И ему сложно было бы отделить те, которые относятся к нему лично от тех, которые адресованы кому-то другому. Поскольку у нас совсем другая динамика, хотелось бы, конечно, чтобы это настраивалось от сайта к сайту.

Comment: *Не знал, что это есть в справке* при содзании комментария справа есть «кнопка» *справка*, а в развернувшейся краткой справке [есть ссылка](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), где рассказано о том, кто получает оповещения.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, весьма своевременный вопрос. Из-за нынешней системы нотификаций, которая (IMHO) убивает интерес к сайту пишу здесь (жаль, Regent не увидит, но не плодить же вручную по комментарию для каждого из участников темы).

Comment: @avp: А почему бы не сделать feature request отдельным вопросом?

Comment: @VladD, вероятно, нужно. про уведомления: а) об изменениях ответов; б) о комментариях к ответам, в которых автор вопроса явно не упомянут.

Comment: @VladD, как «зачинатель», сейчас постараюсь сформулировать feature request.

Comment: @avp : [сформулировал](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587/178576)