# Уведомления автору вопроса об изменении ответов и о комментариях к ответам

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, уведомления

По итогам [обсуждения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/584/178576) родилось предложение:

Если это технически возможно, реализовать подписку на уведомления (все, или хотя бы суммарные за небольшой промежуток времени) о *любой* активности в вопросе:

1. о редактировании ответов к этому вопросу;
2. о комментариях к *ответам* на этот вопрос, даже если участник не упомянут в них явно.

Плюс, хотелось бы автоматическую подписку для автора вопроса,
желательно сделать это в качестве включенной по умолчанию (но отключаемой при желании) опцией в личных настройках.

Comment: ... А если это технически на данный момент невозможно, то пусть это будет feature request.

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил галочку в личных настройках участников, чтобы можно было отписаться от слежения за _всеми_ комментариями, и вернуться к текущему поведению.

Comment: Возможно, ещё стоит сделать как было на Хэшкоде, возможность участнику подписаться/отписаться на уведомления об активности в вопросе вне зависимости от того, принимал он в нём участие или нет.

Comment: @VladD, про галочку — дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @VladD, вот это было бы абсолютно верным решением.

Comment: @avp: Угу, тогда у нас получается просто автоподписка автора на активность по вопросу (которую можно при желании отключить).

Comment: @VladD, и не только автора, но и всех заинтересованных участников (даже не активных в этой теме).

Comment: @VladD, да, `подписка` и `автоподписка для автора` — это идеально. подредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, потому что я не знаком с тем, как это было реализовано на хэшкоде.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: сделано

Comment: @VladD, вспомнил: возможность `подписаться на вопрос` — есть. это «избранное» (звёздочка слева от вопроса). правда, оповещения не поступают в «область уведомлений», а видны только при просмотре «активности» в профиле, но, возможно, это даже и лучше.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Это да, но хотелось бы именно доставки уведомлений.

Comment: @VladD, тогда, я думаю, это уже отдельный f.r.: уведомлять об активности в «избранном» (с возможностью отключения или без).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Не уверен, что комментарии включаются в активность «избранного». Хотя сейчас проверим.

Comment: Напишите комментарий, кто-нибудь!

Comment: @VladD, по-моему, включаются. но лучше проверить.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Интересно, что мне пришла нотификация об изменении в избранных (1 вопрос), но в [списке](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites) вопрос с изменениями не был подсвечен. То есть невозможно определить, у какого же из избранных вопросов произошли изменения. У вас тоже так? Если да, это баг.

Comment: @VladD, нет, мне уведомлений об изменениях в избранном ни разу не поступало. их было видно на вкладке «активность» в профиле, в виде цифры возле слова «избранное» (цифра обозначает количество вопросов, в которых произошли какие-нибудь изменения). а после открытия вкладки «избранное» эти вопросы выделены цветом.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: моя ошибка, я имел в виду нотификацию в профиле, а не в мейлбоксе.

Comment: @VladD, нет, я замечал в некотором роде обратную ситуацию (в частности, буквально пол-часа назад): цифра возле избранного была `3`, «подсвечено» было тоже три вопроса, но один из них не менялся уже два дня: ни комментариев, ни правок не было. правда, может быть, «плюс» или «минус» у какого-нибудь из сообщений поставили, и это-то и вызвало «активацию» — не знаю.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Надеюсь, Николас прояснит ситуацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть [плагин для Chrome StackStalker](https://stackapps.com/questions/493/stackstalker-be-notified-when-your-question-is-updated-chrome-extension), который предоставляет примерно те возможности, о которых идет речь.

[image: StackStalker screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Подобные уведомления — в большинстве случаев бесполезный шум, поэтому большой пользы от них не вижу.

Так как значительная часть активности в вопросе происходит в первые часы со времени его появления, то могу предложить костыль — держать вкладки открытыми. Скорее всего, вас интересует не больше 10 вопросов в день настолько, чтобы следить за всеми обновлениями, поэтому 10 открытых вкладок проблем не доставят. Конечно, обновления надо будет проверять вручную, но их будет сразу видно: появятся плашки "вопрос/ответ оредактирован", "добавлено N комментариев" и т. п.

Если хотите иметь полноценные уведомления прямо сейчас, а не надеяться на чудо, что разработчики SO вдруг решат заняться этой задачей (что-то подобное уже просили, и не раз), то можете воспользоваться StackOverflow API. Там есть возможность отслеживать любые события где угодно. Можете написать расширение к браузеру и генерировать всплывающие уведомления или как-то встраиваться в интерфейс сайта, например.

Что называется, вы же программист. `;-)`

---

Что касается новичков, то тут всё неоднозначно.

Уведомления о правках ответов в целом могли бы быть полезны, но уже имеющийся подход, когда при правке автор ответа пишет комментарий с обращением — не самый плохой, потому что позволяет включить дополнительное пояснение, что именно было добавлено или изменено (новичок навряд ли полезет в историю правок, чтобы прочесть описание исправления, да и вообще их мало кто пишет — только низкореповые юзеры для пояснения предлагаемой правки из-за того, что движок заставляет).

Уведомления о всех комментариях могут быть вредны и приводить к слишком большому количеству шума. Если два пользователя увеклись и развели чат в комментариях, я не хочу видеть свои уведомления забитыми под завязку их болтовнёй. Если кто-то из участников захочет уведомить автора вопроса, то он всегда может это сделать явно.

Нельзя забывать, что чем больше уведомлений, тем больше риск, что их пропустят, особенно новички. Никто не будет разбирать сотню уведомлений о комментариях.

Comment: у меня речь в первую очередь была об уведомлениях для автора вопроса (который чаще всего абсолютный новичок на сайте). см., пожалуйста, ссылку в начале вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Добавил разбор ситуации с новичками.

Comment: 1. в дискуссиях к этому вопросу и к [тому вопросу](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583/178576) вспоминали и про «шум» в том числе (слово «суммарные» попало и в этот вопрос). 2. по поводу сложившейся практики — согласен. но, может быть, стоит её «сломать»?

Comment: по поводу «старичков»: в дискуссии к этому вопросу всплыла информация про «избранное», которое, возможно, удовлетворяет одному из аспектов, озвученных в вопросе.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не согласен. Для меня это была бы полезная штука.

Comment: @avp, а если уведомления про «избранное» будут «всплывать» (по умолчанию — отключено) в области уведомлений, это удовлетворит «старичковым» потребностям?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, если честно, совсем не понял. Раньше приходили письма на мыло с уведомлениями об изменениях. Теперь  этого нет и надо думать не бужет. Ладно. Теперь уведомление -- это красная отметка (в виде какой-то коробочки) на странице, из которой при нажатии выпадает список. Вот в этом списке мне и хотелось бы видеть ссылки на изменненные темы в которых я заинтересован.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, если тема при появлении комментария (или другой правке) будет перемещаться наверх на главной странице, то я тоже возражать не буду (но это не отменяет личную нотификацию)

Comment: *Раньше приходили письма* — они и сейчас приходят, но раз в заданный промежуток времени (по помяти: три часа, день, неделя). *уведомление -- это красная отметка* — под красной отметкой я подразумевал «область уведомлений», а под «уведомлением» — сам факт извещения об изменениях.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, т.е. в результате выяснили, что мы говорим об одном и том же.

Comment: @avp, на всякий случай повторю то, что затрагивалось в соседней ветке: уведомления (т.е., информирование) об активности в «избранных» вопросах — есть. но оно локализовано на странице профиля, и не «выскакивает» в область уведомлений (вверху слева, белой цифрой на красном фоне), и, соответственно, не попадает в `email`-рассылку.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, значит не там и так реализовано (если избранные это те, которые задаются кликом по звездочке).

Comment: @avp, да, логично было бы отправлять уведомления об активности в «избранных» вопросах в том же информационном письме, где (пребывающий в оффлайне) пользователь извещается о пока не просмотренных сообщениях, попавших в *область уведомлений* (в ту самую белую цифру на красном фоне).