# Как правильно использовать модель вопросов и ответов Stack Overflow?

Tags: обсуждение, faq, правила

Иногда, некоторые участники сетуют, что далеко не все обсуждения можно вписать в модель вопросов и ответов. Как результат, возникают споры о необходимости строго придерживаться модели вопросов и ответов Stack Exchange.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно дискутировать так, чтобы не выходить за рамки формата Stack Overflow?

Comment: только в чате. иначе расстрел на месте.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Под "дискутировать" я имел в виду общаться: задавать вопросы, публиковать ответ и комментировать. Моя вина, не лучшее слово подобрал. Вопрос о том, как правильно использовать сайт. Например, что надо вносить правки, вместо комментариев.

Comment: А как перейти в чат с вопрошающим, если у него недостаточно репутации?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Термины**

*Задающий* - участник, который ищет помощь сообщества.
*Отвечающий* - участник, который хочет поделиться знаниями.

#### Базовый вариант диалога

1. Задающий публикует вопрос.
2. Отвечающий публикует ответ.
3. Задающий отмечает ответ верным.

#### Расширенный вариант диалога

1. Задающий публикует вопрос.
2. Отвечающий добавляет уточняющий комментарий.
3. Задающий уточняет вопрос (вносит улучшающую правку).
4. Отвечающий публикует ответ.
5. Задающий добавляет уточняющий комментарий (запрашивает больше деталей).
6. Отвечающий улучшает ответ (вносит улучшающую правку).
7. Задающий отмечает ответ верным.
8. Комментарии удаляются, если не несут смысловую нагрузку.

#### Дискуссии

Stack Overflow на русском - это сайт вопросов и ответов, который существенно отличается от традиционных интернет-форумов (дискуссионных-форумов), объединяя в себе черты вики-энциклопедий, коллективных блогов, лент новостей и собственно форумов.

[image: сайт вопросов и ответов]

Хотя одной из целей проекта является восполнения недостатка профессионального общения на работе, дискуссии как таковые выходят за рамки формата Stack Overflow на русском. Причина тому - знания. Расширенные дискуссии вносят слишком много шума в образовательную составляющую. В модели Stack Overflow на русском существует две возможности построения диалога.

1. **В чате**. В случае если вам необходимо продолжить расширенную дискуссию с автором вопроса или ответа, вы можете пригласить его в чат. На общение в чате нет каких-либо ограничений за исключением того, что крайне желательно, чтобы результатом такой дискуссии стало улучшение вопроса и/или ответа. *Пожалуйста, не забывайте вносить улучшающие правки в ваши сообщения после обсуждения в чате!*
2. **Комментарии и улучшающие правки**. Основная идея.

   1. Задающий публикует вопрос.
   2. Отвечающий запрашивает уточнения в комментарии.
   3. Задающий дополняет вопрос.
   4. Отвечающий удаляет комментарий.
   5. Повторять пункты 2 - 4 до тех пор пока вопрос не достигнет необходимого качества.
   6. Отвечающий публикует ответ.
   7. Задающий запрашивает уточнения ответа в комментарии.
   8. Отвечающий дополняет ответ.
   9. Задающий удаляет комментарий.
   10. Повторять пункты 7 - 9 до тех пор пока ответ не достигнет необходимого качества.

   *Особые случаи*. Если вы видите, что отвечающий опубликовал ответ, но не до конца понял ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, **внесите улучшающую правку в вопрос вместо добавления нового комментария**! Аналогично, пожалуйста, вносите улучшающую правку в ваш ответ, после обновления вопроса или других случаях, вместо добавления комментария к вопросу или вашему ответу.

#### Ответы на свои вопросы

Эту модель также можно назвать “*моделью заметок*”. Она крайне полезна в тех случаях, когда мы не хотим запоминать наизусть что-то (например, ключи команды `tar`), но хотели бы, чтобы информация всегда была под рукой.

1. Задающий сталкивается с задачей по работе.
2. Задающий формулирует проблему и публикует её в виде вопроса.
3. Задающий выполняет поиск.
4. После нахождения решения задачки, задающий публикует ответ к своему вопросу.

Таким образом можно решить три важные задачи.

1. Повысить качество и разнообразие публикуемых вопросов.
2. Пополнить базу прикладных решений.
3. Оптимизировать свою работу, ведь нам не придется искать заново, в случае повторного появления подобной задачи.

Answer (score 2):

мне кажется, имеет смысл сохранить текущую модель, но с некоторыми дополнениями:

- по умолчанию оповещать автора вопроса не только о комментариях к вопросу, но и о комментариях к ответам, а также и об изменениях ответов.
  сделать такое дополнение отключаемым и глобально в настройках профиля, и, по возможности, для любого из вопросов. т.е., некий аналог «автоматического добавления в избранное». обсуждалось [*здесь*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/587/178576) и [*здесь*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/583/178576).
- более «агрессивно» (после меньшего количества комментариев) предлагать перенести дискуссию в чат, разрешив делать такой перенос и новичкам, не набравшим 20 баллов репутации. обсуждалось [*здесь*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/591/178576).

Comment: Второй пункт полностью поддерживаю. Первый интересен, но нужно уточнить подробности. А вообще, почему бы не отдельным вопросом два [meta-tag:feature-request]?

Comment: Разве в Q&A автор вопроса не оповещается о комментариях в любом месте темы?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, не совсем понял, что вы подразумеваете под «в q&a», но автор вопроса не оповещается о (не адресованных явно ему) комментариях к ответу (если, конечно, он не единственный комментатор этого ответа).

Comment: Я имел в виду конкретно движок StackExchange. Никак не могу привыкнуть к тому, что у него нет своего имени.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: а если он единственный комментатор, тогда разве оповещается? (разумеется, если без @).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если **под ответом** кто угодно (например, автор вопроса) общается с автором ответа, и никто третий в беседу не вмешивается, то оповещения получают оба собеседника (без всяких там `@`).