# Автор вопросов не отмечает решения

Tags: обсуждение, неотвеченные-вопросы

Человек [получил ответы на 24 вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211331/?tab=questions), но только в двух отметил решение. Для меня такая отметка важна трижды:

1. как местная валюта;
2. как обратная связь (правильно ли понял вопрос, понятно ли объяснил, все ли обстоятельства учёл и т.д.);
3. как дополнительная информация (что помогло решить задачу, удалось ли её вообще решить).

Ловлю себя на нежелании читать новые вопросы этого автора. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Расстрелять...)

Comment: Намекнуть ему в комментариях? Может ему совсем не очевидны причины и последствия появления зеленых галок у ответов?

Comment: Не смотреть, кто автор вопросов, просто отвечать на интересные.

Comment: на заре SO присутствовал индикатор: "accept rate", но потом его ([заслужено](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/137096)) убрали. Не важно, кто задал вопрос, если он полезен.

Comment: господи, нашли на что смотреть, за чем гнаться. просто давайте хорошие ответы, исправляйте плохие. с этой вашей "местной валютой" тоже как бы слегка неловкое заявление. Не читайте вопросы автора или пишите очень кльовые ответы, если вам есть что сказать по этой теме. Мы сюда пришли не зарабатывать "местную валюту", а давать хорошие ответы. Хороший ответ, одобрен он автором или нет вам итак зачтется.

Comment: @strangeqargo Что скажете по второму и третьему пунктам моего вопроса?

Comment: по второму и третьему пунктам, если у вас, будет, допустим, плохой ответ, вас поправят, иначе - заплюсуют. Я не считаю нужным подталкивание пользователей  к одобрению и плюсованию ответов просто потому, что и на ru и на eng SO встречаются очень плохие или даже вредные ответы.

Comment: @strangeqargo Кажется, вы отвечаете на что-то другое. Цитирую свой вопрос: `Для меня такая отметка важна <...> как обратная связь (правильно ли понял вопрос, понятно ли объяснил, все ли обстоятельства учёл и т.д.); как дополнительная информация (что помогло решить задачу, удалось ли её вообще решить)`. Здесь всюду говорится про отметку о принятии ответа как решения.

Comment: это *не важно*. если автор не понял или не счел нужным отметить ваш ответ полезным, хотя и воспользовался вашим ответом, вы ничего не можете с ним сделать. это просто *не важно*, вас другие спросят (или пошлют) если ответ плохой. Не надо тратить на это свое время. И да, не читайте этого автора, если только вы не даете офигенно крутые ответы по тематике его вопросов. Постепенно он проэволюционирует до идеи фидбэка, а если нет - ... уйдет.

Answer (score 33):

Вы отвечаете не конкретному человеку, а тысячам других людей, которые зачастую даже не зарегистрированы на портале. Спрашивающий лишь источник вопроса, а отмеченная галка лишь индикатор, требуется ли ему конкретно дальнейшая помощь.

Автор на портале 45 дней, это не так много, чтобы разобраться в механике портала требуется время, тем более не все могут уделять ему слишком много времени. Не думаю, что стоит заставлять всех действовать по шаблону.

Если участник задает вопросы, на которые дают ответы, он безусловно полезен для сообщества.

Если покопаться вы найдете и других участников, например, у которых отрицательных голосов больше, чем положительных или которые взяли больше кармы, чем отдали голосами. Это все нормально, каждый из участников полезен только тем, что присутствует и участвует в сообществе. Чем оно больше, тем устойчивее и правильнее работает. Поэтому лучше всего работать на увеличение его объема, а для этого нужны интересные вопросы и ответы, не оглядываясь на карму и отмеченные ответы.

Answer (score 4):

> #### Автор вопроса — наша связь с реальностью

Сайт не просто собирает ответы на вопросы, он помогает с задачами из практики. Поэтому важно не только ответить, а уточнить понимание задачи в начале и проверить отдачу от решения в конце.

Участники могут открыто делиться опытом и блистательно разжёвывать теорию. Их ответы могут получать уйму голосов, но без диалога с автором никто не узнает:

- что задача понята неправильно и все ответы — мимо;
- что ответ не сработал в конкретных условиях;
- что автор спросил [не о том, что нужно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/208926);
- что помог ответ, который заминусовали.

Поэтому хороший ответ появляется [в результате взаимодействия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/691/208926): вопрос — уточнение — ответ — доработка — отметка о решении. За это время и вопрос, и ответ меняются. Иногда — до неузнаваемости.

> #### Молчание автора не скомпенсируешь

У отметки о решении — особый статус. Если ответ выручил на практике, то он заслуживает внимания. И, напротив, незакрытый вопрос дискредитирует все предложенные варианты: как доверять тому, что не сработало?

Поэтому одна часть ответа на мой вопрос — работать на широкий круг читателей. Вторая — разбираться, как влияет на сайт поведение каждого из нас. Третья — узнать, почему конкретный человек не отмечает решения. Четвёртая — сделать ситуацию штатной:

- подготовить шаблоны комментариев, чтобы находить нужные слова даже уставшим;
- переписать инструкции, чтобы польза от отметок стала понятней;
- настроить механику сайта, чтобы ещё мягче и эффективней вовлекать во взаимодействие друг с другом.

И, думаю, много ещё чего. Вряд ли в этом вопросе появится отметка о решении ;)

Comment: Про связь с реальностью понравилось.

Answer (score 0):

Было бы не плохо показывать статистику вопросов автора, сколько задано и сколько отмечено как верный. Так можно сразу решить, стоит отвечать такому пользователю или нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вопросов много, в профиле автора придётся листать заданные вопросы и подсчитывать на глаз, что не очень хорошо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возьмите API Stackoverflow и напишите небольшое расширение для браузера, которое будет показывать то, что нужно - и ноу проблемо)

Answer (score -3):

Я всё-таки дам ещё один вариант ответа.

Ответ @cheops является ответом гуманистическим, вопросом экстравертного типа,  в нём говорится о сообществе, о пользе человечеству. Это всё правильные вещи и я согласен с ними, поставил плюс.

Тем не менее я хочу сконцентрировать ответ на внутренних вещах, на психологии.

Вы ловите себя на негативных эмоциях. Неприязнь, отторжение - это те, которые вы заметили. У некоторых в подобных случаях проявляется ещё например обида и/или агрессия (не всегда осознаваемая, подобные чувства часто успешно вытесняются), я надеюсь, что вам повезло больше и вы такие чувства не испытываете.

Подобными негативными эмоциями вы причиняете вред самому себе.

Понимаете ли, что это именно вы причиняете себе вред (а не тот человек, что не ставит галку) и что это именно ваша зона ответственности?

И, пожалуй, главный вопрос: а хотите ли вы и дальше продолжать причинять себе вред?

Западная цивилизация предлагает экстравертные способы решения проблемы (поменять мир снаружи: крестовые походы на иноверцев с целью перекрестить в свою веру, переубедить/уничтожить несогласных и т.п.), но реально ли отгородиться от всех таких людей, запереть ворота soRU и никогда с ними не встречаться?

Восточные цивилизации говорят, что если ты не можешь поменять мир снаружи -- то всегда можно по крайней мере поменять своё отношение к происходящему.

Тот человек и тот случай -- лишь лакмусовая бумажка, индикатор, способ разобраться в себе.

Подумайте, возможно ли, что вы слишком потребительски относитесь к другим людям ("ты мне, я тебе"); что слишком тщеславны и кармодрочер; что слишком жадны и стараетесь выцарапать из горла каждый плюс в карму; возможно у вас были проблемы с признанием в детстве или вы хотите что-то доказать родителям; возможно... да много чего ещё возможно -- всё это лишь варианты, да и то, которые в обычных ситуциях обычно не заметны, а в подобных случаях проявляются более ярко.

Общего рецепта что с этим делать нет. Просто делайте то, что вам нравится, не завидуйте другим, помните, что в целом люди неплохие и вам воздаётся по заслугам.

Comment: Не, это продуктивное раздражение. Я знаю, что с ним сделать, и куда податься, если что. Не вешайте на меня лишнего.

Comment: Интересно, в  какой формулировке вы это увидели? Везде слово "возможно" фигурирует. Если вас как-то задевает - извините, но у меня и в мыслях не было обидеть.

Comment: Я давал ответы, которые собирали больше плюсов, но не были отмечены как верный. А также ответы, после которых автор вообще не появлялся и не грущю

Comment: @Doofy а я как упёртый солипсист сам задаю вопросы и сам отвечаю ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тоже люблю так делать) Причём очень давно [questions/395171](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/395171)